# EJBCA - Request contiguous certificates

Tags: x509certificate, ejbca

I want to use EJBCA with no modifications and preferably without writing proprietary software calling their interface.

I need to create 4 types of certificates. Each certificate will be valid for 5 years but the private key can only be used for 7 days. I want to create 26 certificates in 1 go (so for the next half year), which follow each other exactly to the second. So Cert2 starts a week after Cert1 etc. Can I easily achieve this with EJBCA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use custom start and end days when issuing certificates. Either in the Web UI, or you can use the SOAP API, which has a scriptable command line interface (clientToolBox).